# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Adapter disappears after it is deployed

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

I am trying to deploy multiple adapters to a Worklight Server in a production environment. When refreshing the console, the deployed adapters are missing.

What is the problem?

Comment: The text as written does not make any sense. Please rephrase and add more information. Any errors in the log files?

Comment: My guess is that you are trying to deploy your adapter to your production server from your Worklight studio. Try instead to use the browse button in your production console and search for the adapter in your file system and upload it manually.

Comment: Are there no errors? What does the console show? What does the production server log show?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please take a look at your Worklight Server log to see if any errors are displayed. I have seen in the past similar behavior when adapter procedures relied on security-tests, but the security tests were not defined properly in the authenticationConfig.xml file on the server side. In the server log I saw the following error:

"Failed to deploy adapter. This may be due to a JavaScript error in your adapter implementation"

If this is the case please update your authenticationConfig.xml on your production server to match the properties you have defined in your development environment. Also do these adapters deploy successfully in your development environment when running locally?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Studio the adapter was created in and the Server the adapter is deployed to are of **the exact same build number**

This is reason #1 for adapters to get deployed and then immediately get removed.